# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs at “Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.”

Tags: 16.04, boot, login, tty

As per the title, I am facing this issue.

Followed the top answer in the following link:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252603/debian-jessie-boot-hangs-at-started-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes

After reboot, the issue is still there.

Installation of nvidia driver is the last thing I did before facing this issue.

Edit (Process that was made):

1. Boot into recovery mode.
2. Remove the nvidia driver using the
   command: sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*